# How to suppress Autodiscover Redirect warnings via GPO?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, group-policy

Our users keep getting the Autodiscover redirect warnings in Outlook, even when they select "Don't inform me about this website again", the message comes back in a few days.

I want to suppress this message for once and for all. Autodiscover appears to be working correctly on all clients.

Is there a way to suppress this message on all cients at once, for example via GPO?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found this old question whilst looking for the same thing. I haven't found a way to do this with a GPO yet, but this can be done in the registry like so:

1. Close Outlook.
2. Start Registry Editor.
3. Locate and then click to select the following registry subkey:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover\RedirectServers`

*Note You can also use the following registry subkey:*

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover\RedirectServers`

*Where xx is 12.0 for Outlook 2007, 14.0 for Outlook 2010, 15.0 for Outlook 2013, and 16.0 for Outlook 2016*

4. Click the Edit menu, point to New, and then click String Value.
5. Type the name of the HTTPS server to which AutoDiscover can connect without warning for the user, and then press ENTER.

For example, to allow a connection to `https://contoso.com`, the first String Value (REG_SZ) name would be as follows: `contoso.com`

*You do not have to add text to the Value data box. The Data column should remain empty for the string values that you create. To add more HTTPS servers to which AutoDiscover can connect without displaying a warning, repeat steps 4 and 5 for each server.

6. On the File menu, click Exit to exit Registry Editor.

(taken from [Microsoft Support Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-za/help/2783881/how-to-suppress-the-autodiscover-mismatch-warning-in-outlook-2007-and))

I haven't found a pre-existing policy to use to create a GPO, but you could create your own to set those registry values instead.

Comment: Thx for the answer @neildeadman. Our issue has long been solved (don't know anymore how we did it) yet I am sure your answer will be helpful for others.

Comment: I always wonder which GPO setting you manipulate, when editing a value under Software\Policies. I'm so annoyed that even Microsoft suggests to edit values there. You wouldn't know the corresponding policy, would you?

Comment: I don't I'm afraid.